# what is difference between define property for fill them

Tags: c#, properties

i see two kind of property define in c# language,what is difference between and when have us each:

```
public class _parentBLL
{
    public ClassA class_A => new ClassA();
    public ClassB class_B { get; } = new ClassB(); 
}
```

Comment: 1) [Expression-bodied properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) (C# 6+). 2) [Auto property initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#auto-property-initializers) (C# 6+)

Comment: @Jimi thanks,i understand first property how to work, but i not find out what differece with 2th

Comment: 1) Read-only (getter): returns a value (expanded with setter in C# 7.0+). 2) Initializer: assigns an initial value to the property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are just syntactic sugars and are equivalent to the following:

```
public class _parentBLL
{
    public ClassA class_A
    {
        get { return new ClassA(); }
    }

    private readonly ClassB _class_B = new ClassB();
    public ClassB class_B
    {
        get { return _class_B; }
    }
}
```

Note the difference: *_parentBLL.class_A* creates and returns a new instance of *ClassA* every time when the getter is invoked while *_parentBLL.class_B* always returns the same instance of *ClassB*.

A remark:
I advise to follow the C# naming convention: names of classes and properties are pascal cased.